# How to divide first 4 list value into column in dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas DataFrame of empty values in column Something like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['A','B','C','D'])
```

i have a list Something like this:

```
list_imp  =  [1,5,7,5,2,7,4,7,2,8,8,3,0,9,6,9]
```

what i want is the first four values should be inserted inside column A next four values inside column B next four values inside column C and next 4 values inside column D. Is it possible to do so?

```
       A  B  C  D
       1  2  2  0
       5  7  8  9
       7  4  3  6
       5  7  8  9
```

Comment: Use `reshape` with an `'F'-order`: `np.reshape(list_imp, [-1,4], order='F')`

Answer (score 1):

Use `np.array` with `np.T`, to first create a matrix and then transform it to correct shape:

```
list_imp  =  [1,5,7,5,2,7,4,7,2,8,8,3,0,9,6,9]
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array(list_imp).reshape(-1,4).T, columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])

   A  B  C  D
0  1  2  2  0
1  5  7  8  9
2  7  4  8  6
3  5  7  3  9
```

Comment: if i try the same with list_imp of values 104 and 26 columns it gives error     np.array(Values_Obtained).reshape(4,4).T

ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 104 into shape (4,4)

Comment: Thanks @Erfan its working can you please explain np.array(list_imp).reshape(-1,4).T,

Comment: `np.array` makes your list an array for the next numpy operation (reshape). `reshape(-1,4)` makes your array any number of rows (-1) with 4 columns. The `.T ` transposes your matrix to make the rows into columns to fit your criteria, otherwise 1,5,7,5 would be the first values of A, B, C, D and not the values of A.